# Combine selector conditions

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to combine several conditions to select row/columns from an array.

Given a matrix `A`, I know that

```
A[:, [1,3]]
```

gives me the second and fourth column. Also,

```
A[:, :3]
```

works like a charm. However, I fail to combine the conditions:

```
A[:, [:3, 6, 7]]
```

gives me a syntax error. How can I get this selection going?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, you can do:

```
A[:, range(3) + [6, 7]]
```

or

```
A[:, np.r_[:3, 6, 7]]
```

To understand why your first try didn't work, you need to understand a bit more about how general python indexing and how numpy's indexing works.

---

First off, slicing notation is only valid inside of a slice, so `blah = [:3, 6, 7]` is invalid python syntax, as you're constructing a new list in that case. (You're implicitly doing this with `A[:, [:3, 6, 7]]`. The second set of brackets makes a new list.)  Numpy has a special (but often hated upon) operator to use slicing notation to construct something similar to what you're wanting: `np.r_`.  For example:

```
In [1]: print np.r_[:3, 6, 7]
[0 1 2 6 7]
```

Notice that we could get more-or-less the same result (`np.r_` returns an array, the next example will return a `list`) by adding two lists together:

```
In [2]: print range(3) + [6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 6, 7]
```

---

However, it's also important to understand what's going on behind the curtains with numpy.  There are two general types of indexing in numpy. "Normal" indexing uses slices of any sort and returns a view of the array. The data isn't copied.  "Fancy" indexing uses an arbitrary sequence of items (e.g. a list) and copies the data.

Because anything that can be described by standard slicing notation has regular steps (i.e. a start, end, and step interval), you can make a new array without copying the original data.  (Numpy arrays have to be "regularly strided" in memory. You can make a reference to "every third item" without copying data, but not "items 2, 5, and 6" because there's no regular pattern to the latter.)

All this may seem confusing, but here's an example of why it matters. Let's make an example array and slice it two different (but equivalent) ways:

```
In [1]: a = np.arange(18).reshape(3, 6)

In [2]: a
Out[2]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])

In [3]: b = a[:, :3]

In [4]: b
Out[4]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [12, 13, 14]])

In [5]: c = a[:, [0, 1, 2]]

In [6]: c
Out[6]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

`b` and `c` look identical.  However, `c` is a new copy of the data in `a` while `b` references the original data.  If we change `c`, `a` won't be modified:

```
In [7]: c[0, 0] = 10000

In [8]: c
Out[8]:
array([[10000,     1,     2],
       [    6,     7,     8],
       [   12,    13,    14]])

In [9]: a
Out[9]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])
```

If we change `b`, `a` *will be modified*:

```
In [10]: a
Out[10]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])

In [11]: b[0,0] = 99999

In [12]: a
Out[12]:
array([[99999,     1,     2,     3,     4,     5],
       [    6,     7,     8,     9,    10,    11],
       [   12,    13,    14,    15,    16,    17]])

In [13]: b
Out[13]:
array([[99999,     1,     2],
       [    6,     7,     8],
       [   12,    13,    14]])
```

This gives you a lot of control over memory use, and allows numpy to be quite efficient (it's *really* important when you start working with very large arrays in memory.).  However, you can be burned by it if you're not aware of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if that's what you are looking for:

```
>>> A = numpy.array([range(10)]*10)
>>> numpy.hstack((A[:, :3],A[:, [6,7]]))
array([[0, 1, 2, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 6, 7]])
>>>
```